# Adverts in iframes are intermittently not rendered in PhantomJS

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

When taking screenshots using PhantomJS it intermittently does not load Google ads which are served within iFrames, a good example can be found at gumtree.com

I am using PhantomJS 2.0.0
OS version : Windows 8.1 Pro

My code:

```
var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36");

var service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.WebSecurity = false;

var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service, options);
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://gumtree.com");
Thread.Sleep(5000);

((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Example screenshot that has not rendered the adverts: http://postimg.org/image/6xp7ilrl3/

Comment: You probably need to wait before rendering

Comment: I have also tried waiting before taking the screenshot - my code example has been updated to include a 5 second wait

Answer (score 0):

Artjom B is right that it is simply a matter of increasing the wait time before taking the screenshot - when I increase the wait time 10 seconds the ads always render.

I do find this odd as firefox / chrome are able to load the iframe ads much faster than Phantomjs on Windows but this is a separate issue.